# Putnam 1941 B6 Triple integral into Single integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I came across this problem in my multivariable calculus book. It was the 1941 Putnam B6 question. I don't know where to start and how to go about doing this? I drew the 2D region and tried going from there but no luck. [1941 Putnam B6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOkcV.png)
Any help on how to approach this problem from a Cal III student view? Also in general, what is a strategy in converting these triple integrals into a single integral?

Comment: This is doable by a Calc III student. Hint: Decompose the unit cube into 6 parts that look like the LHS (up to a suitable change in variables).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

> The integral on the LHS is integrating over the space of $0 \leq x \leq z \leq y \leq 1 $.

**Corollary:** Clearly when we integrate over the 6 permutations of the above inequality chain, we get the unit cube. Hence the equation is true.

---

Technical note:  Some points are satisfied by multiple inequality chains (when there is an equality case), but they have measure 0 so do not affect the integration.

Comment: Two questions. 1) How do you that we are integrating with the bounds 0≤y≤x≤z≤1. In other words, how was this inherently clear to you because it's not to me. Also in the integral, z is between x and y so how is z between x and 1? Likewise for y its between x and 1 (this is coming from the integral bounds.) 2) How is this the unit cube? Aren't cubes supposed to have constant limits of integration? Its very hard to visualize this region.

Comment: 1) (Updated the inequality). $x \leq z \leq y$ follows from the innermost integration. $x \leq y \leq 1$ follows from the second, and $ 0 \leq x \leq 1$ follows from the first. Put that all together, you get the inequality chain $0 \leq  x \leq z \leq y \leq 1$. 2) Note that I said "6 permutations of the inequality chain", where we permutae x, y, z. Given any point in the unit cube, it is clear that it must satsify (at least) one of these inequalities (just arrange the coordinates in increasing order). Conversely, any point that satisfies an inequality chain is obviously in the unit cube